# Find the equation of line d such that H(a,b;c,d)

Tags: projective-geometry

In the Extended Projective Plane, let a be the line with equation x=0, b the line with equation y=x-4, and c with equation y=-x+4. Find the equation of the line d such that H(a,b;c,d).

I understand the process to determine this line d. I would intersect the lines with a line x such that x has equation y=0 and then use the cross ration formula to determine the point D and then find the line through D concurrent with a,b, and c. However, I am not understanding how this process would work with this problem as the three lines a,b, and c are not concurrent and I believed that this was required for four lines to form a harmonic quadruple of lines.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The lines _are_ concurrent.

Comment: How is this so? The lines y=x+4 and y=-x+4 intersect x=0 at (0,4) and (0,-4) and this is not the same point.

Comment: Really? I get $y=4$ after setting $x$ to $0$ in $y=-x+4$.

Comment: I just realized that I have the incorrect equations. I will fix this immediately! It should be y=x-4 and y=-x+4